# How to mask characters such as password in Textbox in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please let me know how to mask characters such as password in Textbox in Window Phone 7.

Like this:

UserName : okame100

Password : ****************************

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a PasswordBox control: http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2010/03/29/windows-phone-7-dev-series-textbox-input-scope/