# How to mask characters in TextBox (Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

I have been looking for a method to mask all characters in TestBox but I coudn't have found.

I have to use TextBox, beacause I have implemented validation styles from my previous question.

PS. I have read the question: 
http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/308
but there is nothing about from where import the class

Do you have some ideas how to mask the characters?

Comment: I think, here is the answear:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928005/how-to-mask-characters-such-as-password-in-textbox-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: I have mentioned that I have to use TEXTBOX instead of PASSWORDBOX

Comment: In that case you must make a new control inherited from TextBox so that it can use TextBox style. The real work is how to synch the real text with user's input using TextChanged and KeyDown event.

Answer (score 1):

Get this:

PasswordBox control: http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2010/03/29/windows-phone-7-dev-series-textbox-input-scope/